# df change color of text based on cell value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

I have a df

```
        val1     val2
f     -45000    -32000
t    -3004000    23000
```

I want text to be formatted in international number format
Tried with styler options but getting issue

```
df.style.format({"${:20,.0f}"})
```

Need output as

```
         val1           val2
f      $-45,000       $-32,000
t      $-3,004,000    $23,000
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: For set formating remove outer `{}` with subset parameter for specify columns names for processing:

```
df.style.format("${:20,.0f}", subset=['val1','val2'])
```

Original solution:

```
df.style.applymap(color_negative_red, subset=['val1','val2'])
```

If need both solutions together:

```
(df.style.applymap(color_negative_red, subset=['val1','val2'])
         .format("${:20,.0f}", subset=['val1','val2']))
```

Comment: how to format the numbers in international format , could you help on it.

Comment: @Madan - Can you edit question?

Comment: @Madan - Can you check now?

Comment: How to apply for specific columns only..

Comment: neat and clear..

Comment: @Madan - Super, answer is completed, do you need join both solutions together?